# Erro utilizando IntelliJ que não acontece no Eclipse - mongoTemplate

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Um projeto que funciona normalmente no Eclipse, não funciona no IntelliJ. Não importa as bibliotecas corretamente.

Log do erro:

```
2021-09-09 10:10:25.058  INFO 6824 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2021-09-09 10:10:25.058  INFO 6824 --- [  restartedMain] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
    2021-09-09 10:10:25.062  INFO 6824 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:212)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
        at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245)
        at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    2021-09-09 10:10:25.290  WARN 6824 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-200]
    2021-09-09 10:10:25.290  INFO 6824 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2021-09-09 10:10:25.294  INFO 6824 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    2021-09-09 10:10:25.295  INFO 6824 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2021-09-09 10:10:25.304  INFO 6824 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2021-09-09 10:10:25.387 ERROR 6824 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************
    Description:
    Field pr in br.com.project.adm.pro.DummyData required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.
    The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    Action:
    Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Trecho do arquivo application.java

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableMongoAuditing
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = 
    { 
        br.com.pro.pls.web.user.SystemRoleRepository.class,
        br.com.pro.pls.web.user.UserRepository.class,
    
    })
```

Arquivo pom.xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> 
        </parent>
        
        <dependencies>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>6.17.0</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>           
                            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20190722</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>dev</id>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
                <properties>
                    <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties> 
                    <project.packaging>jar</project.packaging>               
                </properties>            
                <build>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>show-profiles</id>
                                    <phase>compile</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>            
                    </plugins>
            
                </build>                              
            </profile>       
    
            <profile>
                <id>prod</id>
                <properties>
                    <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
                    <project.packaging>war</project.packaging>
                </properties>   
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                       <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>  
                <build>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                </build>                       
            </profile>
        </profiles>
    
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>Central Repository</name>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>Central Repository</name>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma sugestão é forçar o intellij a "reimportar" todas as dependências.

Para isso:

`Ctrl+Shift+A` -> escreva `reimport` ou `reload`, você vai ver a ação: `Reimport All Maven Projects` ou `Reload All Maven Dependencies...`.

No Mac, o atalho equivalente é `⌘+⇧+A` para encontrar as ações disponíveis.

Uma outra opção, caso não resolva, é fechar o `Intellij`, apagar a pasta `path/do/projeto/.idea` e depois abrir o intellij, abrir o diretório do projeto novamente. Ele vai carregar como se fosse um "novo projeto".

Nesse caso:

```
rm -rf path/to/projeto/.idea
```

Ou no caso do windows:

```
rmdir path/to/projeto/.idea
```